# How to access state values simultaneously for all reuses of the component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the following inside a component:

const [score, setScore] = React.useState (32)

Using the setScore function, I'm generating a new score.

And, I'm reusing the above component 4 times (passing down different props) to generate 4 different scores which I then want to add up. I can display these scores on the UI.

But cannot access all of these 4 scores in the code to generate a grand total. How can I pass down these four scores to a child component to sum up the total.

ps: If this component were used one time, I could pass down the totalScore using totalScore={totalScore}as a prop to the child component. But here I have reused the component.

Comment: why didn't you use array ?

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for your comment. I actually used array. Just for simplicity, I didn't mention it here.

I used the following:
const [score, setScore] = React.useState ([32]) 
and returned the following:
return [newScore, ...score]

I can now access the latest value from score[0]. I used the same component 4 times with different props. Now, once I have the four scores, I want to add them up in a different component. There, I'm struggling to pass down these four scores. Any idea?

Comment: Can you share the full code

Comment: @Rahul My codes are total mess- I'm still sharing the relevant parts from there.

The following is inside a component- <Language />

function LanguageTest (props) {
const [totalScore, setTotalScore] = React.useState ([32])

function scoreUpdate () {
        setTotalScore (prevLanState => {
            const newScore= xArray.filter(num => num[0].includes(lan))[0][1][props.marStatus];
            return [newScore, ...totalScore]
        })
I have the array with all the values . I'm using <Language /> component 4 times with different props. Don't know how to get these 4 totalScore.

Comment: @Rahul I can access the totalScore from the current component. The problem is I used this component 4 times passing down different props. The user uses four different sliders to select the input values. I also can see these 4 totalScore values on the UI. But, I can't use them in the code in a child component to generate a grand total of these 4 scores. My apology if I'm not making any sense! :(

Comment: I recommend that you take a look at react-redux. If you often share states between components, Redux is the tool for you.

Comment: Add code to the question to make it readable and give an insight to the problem.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson Yeah, I'm still learning the ropes! Will head to Redux soon! Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @DragonInTraining Didn't know about the feature! Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: In general, when you wish to share state with several components you have one of three options.:

1. Wrap the components in a `Provider` and use the `createContext` API to pass a common context. 
2. Use a global state library like Redux for the shared state.
3. Move the state logic up to a common parent component and pass the state and updaters as props.

Pick your poison. I suggest context.

Comment: @CesarNapoleonMejiaLeiva Wow- thanks so much for the feedback! So much more to do then! I gotta learn them first! But, I thought as I can already see these 4 different values in the UI, it would be an easy thing to just get these values and then pass them down to a child component where I could generate the grand total. Thanks again for your suggestions! Kudos!

Comment: If you cannot access the state then that component has no connection to <Language /> right? It is a seperate component right? If that the case you have to make your state globally accessible like @Casar Napolean Mejia Leiva said using  __React Context__

Comment: @Rahul Yeah- it's a separate component. I thought, I could pass down the scores from the 4 reuses (<Language />,  <Language />, <Language />, <Language />) through props to a child component and use the scores to sum up and then show the grand total in the UI.
I'll be looking at Context as Cesar pointed out! Thank you once again for your feedback! Kudos!